# Retrieving part of a Json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have not yet used Json so this is very new to me. However, I am working on a system that outputs a json string from which I have to retrieve a single object to use in a js script.

This is the output

```
{
    "SecureZoneSubscriptionList": {
        "EntityId": 51350993,
            "Subscriptions": [{
            "ZoneName": "FACCM    Membership",
                "ZoneId": "6460",
                "ExpiryDate": "9/5/2014 12:00:00 AM",
                "SellAccess": true,
                "CostPerPeriod": "0.1",
                "CycleType": ""
        }, ]
    }
}
```

How can I retrieve JUST the expiryDate?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read this http://www.json.org/js.html?

Comment: Just `JSON.parse`, then access the attribute. The other option is regex, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: `parsedJSON['SecureZoneSubscriptionList']['Subscriptions'][i]['ExpiryDate']` where _0 <= i <= 0_ in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it easier to see:

```
{
  "SecureZoneSubscriptionList": {
    "EntityId": 51350993,
    "Subscriptions": [
      {
        "ZoneName": "FACCM Membership",
        "ZoneId": "6460",
        "ExpiryDate": "9\/5\/2014 12:00:00 AM",
        "SellAccess": true,
        "CostPerPeriod": "0.1",
        "CycleType": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

so you would do the following:

```
var data= {"SecureZoneSubscriptionList": {"EntityId": 51350993,"Subscriptions": [{"ZoneName": "FACCM Membership","ZoneId": "6460","ExpiryDate": "9/5/2014 12:00:00 AM","SellAccess": true,"CostPerPeriod": "0.1","CycleType": ""}]}};
var expiryDate = data.SecureZoneSubscriptionList.Subscriptions[0].ExpiryDate;
```

if you're retrieving it as a string from a server response, you would JSON.parse to get the object

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"SecureZoneSubscriptionList": {"EntityId": 51350993,"Subscriptions": [{"ZoneName": "FACCM Membership","ZoneId": "6460","ExpiryDate": "9/5/2014 12:00:00 AM","SellAccess": true,"CostPerPeriod": "0.1","CycleType": ""}]}}');
var expiryDate = data.SecureZoneSubscriptionList.Subscriptions[0].ExpiryDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON data is simply a javascript object. JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation. Therefore you can get your data the same way as if your were traversing object attributes in JS:

```
var string = {"SecureZoneSubscriptionList": {"EntityId": 51350993,"Subscriptions": [{"ZoneName": "FACCM Membership","ZoneId": "6460","ExpiryDate": "9/5/2014 12:00:00 AM","SellAccess": true,"CostPerPeriod": "0.1","CycleType": ""},]}}

var expiryDate = string.SecureZoneSubscriptionList.Subscriptions[0].ExpiryDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided this:

```
var fromServer = {"SecureZoneSubscriptionList": {"EntityId": 51350993,"Subscriptions": [{"ZoneName": "FACCM Membership","ZoneId": "6460","ExpiryDate": "9/5/2014 12:00:00 AM","SellAccess": true,"CostPerPeriod": "0.1","CycleType": ""},]}}
```

you would access the ExpiryDate as such:

```
var expDate = fromServer.SecureZoneSubscriptionList.Subscriptions[0].ExpiryDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** the best answer. The best answer is by far is to parse the JSON and access your value through the resulting object. Having said that, JSON is a string. When you need data from a string, regular expressions is always an option.

```
var myString = '{"SecureZoneSubscriptionList": { "EntityId": 51350993, "Subscriptions": [{ "ZoneName": "FACCM    Membership", "ZoneId": "6460", "ExpiryDate": "9/5/2014 12:00:00 AM",    "SellAccess": true,  "CostPerPeriod": "0.1",  "CycleType": ""        }, ] } }';
var matches = myString.match(/"ExpiryDate":\s?"([^"]*)"/);
alert(matches[1]);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bRZFz/1/)**